# Singular / plural form of the noun ‘type’ (meaning printed letters or typeface) – what are the rules?

Tags: grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

When is the noun **type** (meaning typeface or text set in type) used in singular form and when is it used in plural form?

Is it  referred to as a *singulare tantum*?

In which case is it an *uncountable* noun and in which case is it *countable*?

For example which one is correct and why?

> Serif **type** is based on the formal principles of letterforms of the fifteenth century.

> Serif **types** are based on the formal principles of letterforms of the fifteenth century.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the letters for printing"? Do you mean the little blocks of metal (or wood) which are composed in a galley? Do you mean a *typeface* (a particular collection of letterforms)? Or something else?

Comment: I mean a collection of letterforms. For example a group of typefaces with specific features such as sans serif typefaces, or decorative typefaces.

Comment: They are called fonts. Please see [**font²**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/font).

Comment: See typography-- the art and study of the anatomy of written letters.                                   --> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typography

Comment: The question is grammatical. When is the noun **type** (as in typeface or font or collection of letterform) used in plural form with an -s? ––> Which example is correct and why? ––> _Ideas for the design of new **types**._ or _Ideas for the design of new **type**._

Comment: I think that most people who are reasonably literate in English would avoid using "types" to refer to fonts or typefaces or individual letters used in typesetting, simply because it can be very confusing.  Even the singular "type" can be confusing, and "font" or "typeface" is preferred.

Comment: If you ask someone for "Ideas for the design of new type" they will say "a new type of what?"

Comment: @Weather Vane – granted that it is a weak example. What about _The text of the book is set in 10 point type._ or _The text of the book is set in 10 point types._

Comment: The first: type, but here you have some context.